# numbers-based puzzle problem from a Deductive Reasoning section of Intro to Critical Thinking class. What is the optimal way to solve it?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, problem-solving, puzzle

The following puzzle is one of three deductive-reasoning problems (‘brain-teasers’) that were choosable to attempt for an assignment.  Although it posits that "only simple arithmetic and logic" are required to solve it, I suspect that some particular math skills might help greatly.

[image]

What is an optimal method to approach it and satisfactorily find all the solution[s] (in a manner showing that the answer is correct with no missing solutions)?

An initial deduction shows that 9 can belong to only one string-combination (9,3,1), which means that it cannot be a string connector and that (9,3,1) exists which leaves only two other odd letters (5, 7) from the set of 9, and writing out the isolated possibilities for all others 8 thru 1 (although doing so is more exhaustive than an efficient method) yields the number of possible respective combinations being 8=two, 7=two, 6=two, 5=three, 4=four, 3=three, 2=three, 1=three (all more than one).  Also observable is that 13 being odd must consist of an odd number of odds (#= 3 or 1) and an even number of evens (#= 0 or 2), which restricts the possibilities of potential configurations of the entire sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Add $(A+B+C)+(C+D+E)+(E+F+G)+(G+H+I)=52$.
$A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I=45$ so we have $C+E+G=7$
$C,E,G$ must be $1,2,4$ in some order.
The $1$ must be part of two of $1+4+8$, $1+3+9$, and $1+5+7$.  We will rule out $1+5+7$ in a bit.
As you said, $9$ must only be used once.  If it is part of one of the middle runs, $3$ would be used twice, but that is not allowed, so $9$ is part of an end run.  The other end of the other run from $1$ has to be a turn, so it has to be $2$ or $4$.  It cannot be $1+5+7$.
We can start (or end) with either $3,9$ or $9,3$.  Say we start with $9,3$.  Then the next run is $1,8,4$ so we have a proper turn at the end.  The other turn is $2$.  The number between them must be $7$.
One solution is $9,3,1,8,4,7,2,5,6$.  Each end pair may be interchanged, giving four solutions.  We can reverse any of them, giving a total of eight solutions.

Comment: Why must C+E+G = 7?

Comment: @whatyeodds: because $(C + E + G) = (A+B+C)+(C+D+E)+(E+F+G)+(G+H+I) - (A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I) = 52 - 45 = 7$

Comment: @whatyeodds:  adding up the expressions you know to find the sum of all the variables is a common thing in problems like this.

Comment: Why can't the $1$ be part of $1+5+7$?  I see it, but I think it can use some explanation.

Comment: @RobertShore:  Good point.  I added something.  Thanks.

Comment: An easier argument is that no triplet can contain both 1 and 2 (the third number would be 10), so (C,E,G) must have 4 in the middle, i.e. it can only be (1,4,2) or (2,4,1). The other numbers then follow easily.